# Get template for ASP.NET? Get content of another code?

Tags: php, asp.net

I was wondering is there an ASP.NET function that does the same as the `PHP` function `<?php get_template_part ('new','script'); ?>`

Or a function that gets the content of another script for ASP.NET ?

Comment: the function `get_template_part` isn't a native PHP function, I think that it's part of WordPress.

Comment: you could be right about that ...

Comment: Use `asp.Net User Control`
see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET